# "Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url" error on using liquibase-hibernate plugin

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am trying to generate `changeLog` from `diff`s between a Database and Persistence Entities.

I am using the liquibase hibernate plugin

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <configuration>                  
            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        </configuration> 
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>               
    </plugin> 
</plugins>
```

and my `liquibase.properties` goes like this

```
changeLogFile=classpath:liquibase-changeLog.xml
url=jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/oauth_reddit
username=tutorialuser
password=tutorialmy5ql
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
referenceUrl=com.sample.App
  ?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase-diff-changeLog.xml
```

while executing `mvn liquibase:diff`, I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff (default-cli) on project prototype-liquibase-migration: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (com.sample.App?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect) -> [Help 1]
```

I have specified the `Driver` in the `liquibase` properties, but it seems that it is not taking.What could have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

The problem was with my `referenceUrl` in `liquibase.properties` The referenceUrl is using package scan, so the url has to start with `hibernate:spring:`.

I changed

```
referenceUrl=com.sample.App?=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

into

```
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.sample.App?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

This solved my problem.