# Liquibase Hibernate Gradle Plugin diff not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, gradle

I've been trying to get the gradle plugin for liquibase+hibernate working based on several tutorials I have found online, and whenever I try generate the diff, I keep getting the following exception:

```
Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (hibernate:spring:com.project.database.dto?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy)
```

The path: "hibernate:spring:com.project.database.dto" represents the package where all my Hibernate Entities are.

Based on the documentation found here, https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/inspection/diff.html, it seems to be expecting something like

```
jdbc:postgres://localhost...
```

However, when I do that, the diff command works without any errors, but that is incorrect, as it appears to not pick up any changes I made to any of the entities. Based on several tutorials (or for example, this Stack over flow question here: ["Cannot find database driver: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url" error on using liquibase-hibernate plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158781/cannot-find-database-driver-driver-class-was-not-specified-and-could-not-be-de)), it does seem like the "hibernate:spring:..." referenceUrl is needed).

This is my gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.2.0'
}

group 'com.project'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    //spring
    //db--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2
    testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.148'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.6.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.33'
    //db migration ----------------------------------------------------------
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core
    //Liquibase
    implementation group: 'org.liquibase', name: 'liquibase-core', version: '4.21.1'

    liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.16.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:3.0.2'
    liquibaseRuntime 'info.picocli:picocli:4.6.1'
    liquibaseRuntime group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
    liquibaseRuntime("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3")
    liquibaseRuntime("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.6'
    liquibaseRuntime group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.6.0'
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    //unit test
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changelogFile "src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml"
            url "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
            username "user"
            password "pass"
            driver "org.postgresql.Driver"
            referenceUrl "hibernate:spring:com.project.database.dto?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy"
        }
    }
}
```